# how to add path to be used for terminal

Tags: command-line

I'm trying to add PHPUnit to the system path so that I can just use it from any terminal window. I installed PHPUnit using composer, then I added the following lines on the `.bashrc` file in the `HOME` directory then opened a new terminal but it doesn't seem like the terminal recognizes phpunit. Any ideas?

```
PATH=media/wern/Files/tools/vendor/eher/phpunit/bin
PATH=media/wern/Files/tools/vendor/bin
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, environment variables are better set at end of `~/.profile`.

The correct syntax is:

```
PATH=$PATH:/media/wern/Files/tools/vendor/eher/phpunit/bin
PATH=$PATH:/media/wern/Files/tools/vendor/bin
```

so that the two directories are added to `PATH` and do not substitute the previous content.
Also, see that I added a `/` before `media`, because a relative path has no meaning in this context, and I think you did an error.

Last advice, you have to restart your session to see the changes.

Comment: `source ~/.profile` is enough to restart the session, without having to close/open terminal.